# Bazel - how to deal with transitive dependencies of external .so libraries?

Tags: shared-libraries, bazel, rpath

I'm trying to build a binary application with Bazel. This binary depends on an external, pre-compiled library, let's call it `liba.so`. In turn, `liba.so` depends on `libb.so` (this information I obtain via `readelf -d liba.so | grep NEEDED`.

To build this, I have the following setup in Bazel:

```
cc_import(
    name = "liba",
    shared_library = "liba.so",
    deps = [":libb"],
)

cc_import(
    name = "libb",
    shared_library = "libb.so",  
)

cc_binary(
    name = "my_app",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [":liba"],
)
```

Building works fine, however when running (either via `bazel run` or directly) `ldd` fails to find `libb.so`.

I've been reading about this and the reason is that Bazel adds to the `RUNPATH` of the binary only its **direct dependencies**. Since `libb.so` is a transitive dependency, the binary cannot find it.

To solve this, I can think of the following hacks:

- Add ugly linker flags to tell Bazel to add to the `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH`. This is however deemed a bad idea, since `RPATH` is being deprecated and doesn't allow override via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
- Patch the third-party .so file to add to their `RUNPATH`. This works but it doesn't feel good to patch libraries I don't own.
- Make the transitive dependencies direct dependencies of the binary. This is not good, each library should be responsible of its dependencies. The binary doesn't need to know what `liba.so` depends on.

Are there better ways to accomplish this? Other things I've tried without success:

- Use `cc_library` instead of `cc_import`
- Use `data` instead of `deps`.

Thanks!

Comment: Your 3rd point is very debatable: the fact that liba depends on libb might be caused by what you use in liba

Comment: If `liba` contains function `a()`, which in turn calls function `b()` from `libb`, I don't want to link `libb` in my application. Only direct dependencies should be linked

Comment: @AlexGarcia and IMO that should be handled by liba via e.g. feature flags, not my_app. As a user of liba, I care about the API, not the implementation

Answer (score 0):

I was wrestling with this problem for a long time. The first thing I would recommend you to try is to enable

> copy_dynamic_libraries_to_binary

toolchain feature. I think it was primarily designed for Windows but should work for Linux as well.

Now for our purposes, I had to take a more complex, but in the end more reliable approach: I have implemented the aspect which for every binary traverses the dependency graph, collects everything which belongs to the binary output folder and generates file copy actions to place necessary files there when the binary is built. That includes transitive dependencies, but is flexible enough to copy other files we need in the output folder - C++ runtimes, data files, etc. If you are interested I can clip and share relevant code snippets.

Konstantin

EDIT: Per request I crafted a small standalone demo to show how to collect imported dependencies in executable output folder:
https://github.com/Bazel-snippets/transitive_shared_libs

Comment: > If you are interested I can clip and share relevant code snippets.

Hey Konstantin, I'm super interested indeed for the snippet, maybe you can share some pointers?